# Adding Spark and Hadoop configuration files to JAR?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera

I have a Spark application which I would like to configure using configuration files, such as Spark's `spark-defaults.conf`, HBase's `hbase-site.xml` and log4j's `log4j.properties`. I also want to **avoid** having to add the files programmatically.

I tried adding the files to my JAR (under both `/` and `/conf` paths) but when I ran `spark-submit` the configuration files did not seem to have any effect.

To further check my claim I tried running `spark-shell` with the same JARs and checking the contents of the files and I discovered that they were overridden by files from other locations: `/spark-defaults.conf` and `/log4j.properties` were completely different, and `/conf/hbase-site.xml` while staying intact has (probably) had its properties overridden by another JAR's `hbase-default.xml`.

I use CDH 5.4.0.
The files `log4j.properties` and `spark-defaults.conf` were loaded from `/etc/spark/` and `hbase-default.xml` was loaded from `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/jars/hbase-common-1.0.0-cdh5.4.0.jar`.

Is there a way to specify some sort of priority on my configuration files over the others? Should I just configure the files in `/etc/spark` (and perhaps add my `hbase-site.xml` too)? Is there a way to add a custom directory path to the classpath that could take priority over the others?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that it is possible to include the `spark-defaults.conf` into the jar. The only way i know is to edit the file on the server or to add the config settings programatically.

but for `hbase-site.xml` and other hadoop site configs it should work.

you can put every site.xml in the root of your resource directory and it should be loaded unless you have some other site.xml in the classpath of spark which are loaded at first.

i.e. if you are adding `hadoop classpath` or `hbase classpath` to the spark env on the server, then they are in the classloader loaded first, unless you are using the setting `spark.files.userClassPathFirst`